# Dynamics CRM Portal download list button

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-portals

We are using Dynamics CRM Portal. 
When you add an entitylist you may add the "download" feature to that list. 
If I have a page with a list of that entity a "Download" button is displayed.

BUT: If I have an entity form and the list is a subgrid (list of subrecords) there is no "download" button. Can this be configured or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found out myself. 
On the entity form, go to metadata, add an entry, choose "subgrid", choose the correct subgrid, then you can edit the buttons like on the original entity-list.